# Iterate Opening a List of URL's with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, while-loop

I am having trouble iterating the action of opening a list containing URLs using selenium.
the issue is in the part labeled `#Second Part` in my code. `linklinkfin` is a list of length 9 at the moment, but this length can change as more URLs are collected over time. when the code runs, it appears to open the very first URL over and over, and it does not appear to run the append action in the nested while loop since at the end when i print `textreal_listing` it is empty. As the code runs i see https://www.nj.gov/dobi/division_insurance/bfd/enforcement2014.htm opening/refreshing continually till the program ends. At the end of each while loop 1 should get added to `browsercount` and then the code repeats with the new URL but this doesn't appear to be occurring, any ideas?

my code:

```
#FIRST PART
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
textreal_listing=[]
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'\\homedirpva1a01\USERSNC$\603225\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("link")
time.sleep(5)

linkslist=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li/font/a")
linkslist2=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li/font/font/a")
linklinkfin=linkslist+linkslist2

#SECOND PART
textcount=1
textpage=6
browsercount=2014
for i in linklinkfin:
    browser.get("link.htm".format(browsercount))
    time.sleep(2)
    if "404 Error" in browser.page_source:
        browser.get("link.html".format(browsercount))
        time.sleep(2)
        while len(textreal_listing)<100:
            texttreesing=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount))
            textreal_listing.append(texttreesing.text)
            textcount+=1
            if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount)))==0:
                textpage+=3
                textcount=2
                if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount)))==0:
                    break
                browsercount+=1
        else:
            while len(textreal_listing)<100:
                texttreesing=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount))
                textreal_listing.append(texttreesing.text)
                textcount+=1
                if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount)))==0:
                    textpage+=3
                    textcount=2
                    if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount)))==0:
                        break
                browsercount+=1

print(textreal_listing)
```

Comment: Do you see that you never use `i` in your loop?  Of course it always fetches the same page, because you have hardcoded the URL in the `get` calls.  You should probably change that to `for url in linklinkfin:`, and then do `browser.get(url)`.  You might consider `break`ing from the loop when `textreal_listing` exceeds 100, because otherwise you'll loop through the rest of the URLs doing nothing.

Comment: hi Tim. i dont think the url is hardcoded, see the {} within it? .format places the value of `browsercount` within {}, and at the end of the loop 1 is added to `browsercount` to change it and hopefully iterate 9 times. I did try your method but .get must take a string, got an error: 'url' must be a string

Comment: Well, then, what's the point of the loop?  If you never use what's in `linklinkfin`, why collect it?  And remember, if the second or third `find_elements_by_xpath` calls in the `while` loops return nothing, then `browsercount` will not get increments.  What you need to do is start adding some debug prints, so you can see EXACTLY what your queries are returning.  Right now, I believe you are stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Hey Tim, I think you're on the right track with browser.get(url), this should be working. i discovered that `linklinkfin` is a list of webElements, not strings. so i need to convert the webElements into strings to get it working.

Comment: hey tim i got it working using your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked

```
#FIRST PART
import pandas as pd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
textreal_listing=[]
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'\\homedirpva1a01\USERSNC$\603225\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("https://www.nj.gov/dobi/division_insurance/bfd/enforcement.htm")
time.sleep(5)

linkslist=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li/font/a")
linkslist2=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/ul/li/font/font/a")

linktext=[]
for my_href in linkslist:
    linktext.append(my_href.get_attribute("href"))

for my_hrefs in linkslist2:
    linktext.append(my_hrefs.get_attribute("href"))

#SECOND Part
textcount=1
textpage=6
browsercount=2014
for i in linktext:
    browser.get(i)
    time.sleep(5)
    while len(textreal_listing)<100:
        texttreesing=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount))
        textreal_listing.append(texttreesing.text)
        textcount+=1
        if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount)))==0:
            textpage+=3
            textcount=2
            if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td/p[{}]".format(textpage,textcount)))==0:
                break
    
print(textreal_listing)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).